# Force scrbook class to have only oneside option

Tags: koma-script, double-sided, blank-page

In my custom .cls class file I'm using the following code

```
\LoadClass[10pt,twoside=true,open=right,cleardoublepage=empty,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
```

This is ok, but I would like to force oneside option. In fact, when I compile, after chpaters that finish with odd numbers, a blank page is inserted. Here an example:

- Chapter 1 finishes at page 3
- Blank Page
- Chapter 2 starts at page 5

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use `twoside=false` and `open=any`?

Comment: @Sigur Thanks for your reply. Yes I did. The situation is the same. I would remove the blank page (see example).

Comment: What about `oneside=true`? Also, delete the `cleardoublepage`.

Comment: @Sigur It works. Didn't see `open=any` in your previous comment. Please, answer to my question. I will mark as correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Sigur It works also with `cleardoublepage`. Do I need to remove it?

Comment: I don't think so. The solution was with both commands below or only changing the `open` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed by the author on comments above, one solution was possible using `open=any`.

Comment: Only `open=any` is required to have a working solution. But I will set `twoside=false` also. Thank you.